# DocumentID is updating every time in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firebase, singing with gmail on main view. after user singing, I'm saving the *userinfo* based on documentId, if the user already existed(already logged with gmail) person no need to save the information just update information of existed. So I tried some of the code, but I will not achieved what I'm expecting.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

        if let error = error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }

        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication.idToken)!, accessToken: (authentication.accessToken)!)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Login erro  \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
```

Here I check all document id in firestore

```
            self.db.collection("pruser").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                       if let err = err {
                           print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                       } else {
                           for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
//                               print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                            print("\(document.documentID)")
```

Here I have to check with existed Document id's and current user 
Document id. If already existed update info, if not set the values on Document Id but when try with this code

```
            self.ref = self.db.collection("pruser").document()
            let doc = self.ref?.documentID
            print("printdoucment id ",doc!)
                        }
                       }
                   }
}
```

> userid: vnRsxNjJePfwRcAWOLy1iByhV352
>  Doucment id:  PKKLapD9xE9kNNvntI8X
>
> userId: vnRsxNjJePfwRcAWOLy1iByhV352
>  Doucment id: 
>   pxjiVXEgbZgFke3Mijk5

when I logged with existed email also  *documentid* coming different, every login time *DocumentId* is coming different how achieve this issue? [image]

Comment: Have you thought about using the Realtime Database instead? I found it much more beginner friendly and clearer to use.

Comment: @HubertRzeminski thank u for reply my requirement with cloud store.

Answer (score 1):

[document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/CollectionReference#document) with no parameters generates a new document ID every time you call it. You have to pass it a parameter to specify the document ID, if that's what you want.

```
self.db.collection("pruser").document(user.uid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to viewDidLoad():

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController    = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
```

And replace the 7-11 lines with:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials) {
            (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                print("Log in successful")
```

This should sign in the user.

As for DocumentID, I don't think that in your code you've linked each user to each DocumentID. You need to change the or read the DocumentID based on the userid.